# Enum conversion c++

Tags: c++, enums

I have 2 enum values and I am looking to write a function that takes in 1 enum and returns the other

```
    enum MonthLong{January = 1, February, March, April, June,July,August,September
,October,November,December};
enum Month{JAN = January, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY,JUN,JUL,AUG,SEP,OCT,NOV,DEC};
```

for example the function would take in JAN and return "January". It must pass the following BoostCHECK

```
static std::array<std::string const, 13> const names = { "", "January", "February", "March",
    "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October",
    "November", "December" };

for (month_t i = JAN; i <= DEC; ++i)
    BOOST_CHECK(gregorian_month_name(i) == names[i]);
```

I am unsure how to write the function gregorian_month_name

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: edited for clarity I am unsure how to write the function gregorian_month_name

Comment: From the test it looks like you want to convert an enum to a string, not to a different enum.

Comment: Alright that makes sense how would I convert an enum to a string?

Comment: @jsomers89 `names[i]`.

Comment: `enum` are integers so your question has the solution: `return names[i];`. To convert `MonthLong` into `Month`, you can use `return (Month) (monthLong);` where `monthLong` has type `MonthLong`.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified that gregorian_month_name(i) would be in a seperate hpp file, so how would it be aware of what names[i] is?

Comment: Note that iterating over enums is in general a terrible idea. Each one can be an arbitrary integer, so the looping code doesn't necessarily know the next value, and will probably fail spectacularly as soon as you change the enum list.  You're better off using some special struct to wrap your enums for string to enum and enum to string conversion. Then you can have a vector of these structs.

Comment: that may be the best solution